# AVAudioEngine apply audio effects

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, effects, avaudioengine

I am trying to make audio processing application. Is there a way to apply audio effects to audio file using AVAudioEngine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you sure can, You can use:

- AVAudioPlayerNode
- AVAudioUnitDistortion (or any other effect unit)
- engine.outputNode (speaker)

The general connection of the graph looks like:

```
func connectNodes()
{
    engine.connect(unitfilePlayer, to:unitdistortionUnit, format:unitfilePlayerformat)
    engine.connect(unitdistortionUnit, to:unitspeaker, format:engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
}
```

So the graph looks like:

[image: Graph Example]